# Android NullPointerException only in Galaxy SII/III phones

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

In my app, users select from a ListView and it plays a song based on the position. Galaxy SII\SIII phones are throwing NullPointerExceptions when the user tries to select a song. I set the activity to keep the portrait orientation, and have one main layout(activity_main.xml).

Crash Report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.soundboard.MainActivity.playSong(MainActivity.java:466)
at com.soundboard.MainActivity$10.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:286)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1519)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3278)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4327)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting playSong(" + songIndex + ")");
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("Starting playSong("+songIndex+")");
    try {
        if(mp != null){
            mp.release();
        }
        try{
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, songManager.getSong(songIndex).getResId());
        } catch(Exception e){
            FlurryAgent.logEvent("playSong():mediaPlayer.create");
        }
        try{
            mp.prepare();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Caught error preparing: "+e.getMessage());
            FlurryAgent.logEvent("playSong():mediaPlayer.prepare");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();//ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
        FlurryAgent.logEvent("mp.start()");
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songManager.getSong(songIndex).getName();
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();            
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Caught IllegalArgumentException: "+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Caught IllegalStateException: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

    @Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mp != null){
        try{
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in onPause()\n ");
        }
    }
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
}
```

Comment: which line? please make a tag.

Comment: I don't have access to a SII/SIII phone and the emulator isn't catching it, so I can't tell.

Comment: I think he was asking that you mark which line is line 466. That is the line causing the crash.

Comment: It is on mp.start(). So I assume Gabe is correct in that something is not getting initialized, and mp is calling a method on it. I still don't know how to fix this however.

Comment: Just another remark: since you're calling the `MediaPlayer.create()` method that takes a resource id, the returned player will already be prepared. As the javadoc points out: *"On success, `prepare()` will already have been called and **must not be called again**."*. And just to confirm: you are supplying `R.raw.*` resources, right?

Comment: So I should take out all references to mp.prepare() since I am using MediaPlayer.create()? Yeah, I am using R.raw files.

Comment: @clever_trevor: Yes, don't call `prepare()` after creating a `MediaPlayer` through any of the static `create()` helper methods, because the framework returns an already prepared instance. Better said: just follow the documentation, and don't forget to release the instance as soon as you're done with it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MediaPlayer.create fails, then mp can be null.  You'd then call mp.prepare on it, which would crash.  In the case of create failing you want to return from this function and not continue to try to play the song.

Comment: I have a feeling this may be the problem, but I would need a solution unless I would just ignore the Galaxy SII/III phones :(

Comment: The most common cause of that is leaking media player instances.  I see the release above, but do you have other places where a media player may not be released yet mp may be null?  Perhaps around rotation, are you releasing the player in onStop or onDestroy?

Comment: I added the code where I release it in the onPause(). I only have one other usage of mp, which is in the onCreate(): mp = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: That line in onCreate could be your problem-  its created, but never released.  At any rate there's no reason to have it if you're creating new ones via create()

Comment: I initialize it so I can set an onCompletionListener(this) to it. Do you think it would fix the problem if I eliminated the creation in onCreate, or just set the creation to an arbitrary file name?

Comment: If I remove mp=new MediaPlayer(); in onCreate(), then it throws an error.